# setting 'relative' on parent and 'absolute' on inner not working on bottom align bootstrap column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my basic HTML:

```
 <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-xs-8">
        <p>long long long long text that generates taller column</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-4">
        <p>shorter text that generates shorter column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS to make the two columns same height:

```
.row{
    overflow:hidden;
}

[class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom:-99999px;
    padding-bottom:99999px;
}
```

Ok it works, but if I try the traditional parent `relative` and child `absolute` trick I cannot move the inner element `<p>` down to its parent container `<div>`.

```
.col-xs-4{
     position:relative;
}
.col-xs-4 p {
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;//this wont work, but should this setting move it to its 'relative' parent div,'s bottom?
 }
```

Eventually I managed to use a different trick but would like to know why this one is not working. It is because the inner implementation of Bootstrap's grid system?

I am aware that this question might have been previously raised but I could not find the answer, this is the CodePen example of my problem:[an example](https://codepen.io/frostless/pen/gGVKvB)

Comment: @VXp  I commented that out but the symptom still seems to persist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JS avoid disturbing row and column might effect Responsive, This is what you can do

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-xs-8 matchheightog">
        <p>long long long long text that generates taller column</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-4 matchheight">
        <p>shorter text that generates shorter column</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS

```
$(window).on("load resize", function () {
   $(".matchheight").height($(".matchheightog").height());
});
```